# Forcing a string to be bigger than the other

Tags: c++

lets say i have a string containing the month value of a date e.g. (JAN,FEB,MAR,APR and etc). If i want to force a string value of "FEB" to be greater than "JAN", is there a way to do this? I am trying to sort dates but having problem with the month value currently. My date are of fixed string e.g. 12NOV1990, 11DEC1994 etc..

```
struct sortMapDaily: public std::binary_function <bool, std::string, std::string>
{


  bool operator() (const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
  {


      enum month
      {
          JAN,
          FEB,
          MAR,
          APR,
          MAY,
          JUN,
          JUL,
          AUG,
          SEP,
          OCT,
          NOV,
          DEC

      };




     if(lhs.substr(5,4) < rhs.substr(5,4))
     {
         return true;

     }
     else if (lhs.substr(5,4) == rhs.substr(5,4) && lhs.substr(2,3) < rhs.substr(2,3))
     {

         return true;
     }
     else if (lhs.substr(5,4) == rhs.substr(5,4) && lhs.substr(2,3) == rhs.substr(2,3) && lhs.substr(0,2) < rhs.substr(0,2))
     {
         return true;

     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }


  }
};
```

Comment: Yes! You need to write some code

Comment: edited with code, i am unsure of how to map enum to my substring position at (2,3)..

Answer (score 2):

You need to map JAN, FEB with some values, as suggested by *zero298* `enum` is best option.

```
enum Months{JAN,FEB,MARCH};

cout<<JAN<<FEB<<MARCH;
```

> Output: 012

Comment: When tagged C++ why use `printf`?

Comment: @EdHeal changed to cout

Comment: Might want to add some spaces otherwise get '012'

Comment: @EdHeal Sir, you rock.

Comment: It is old age! Along with other things going south

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to create a *class* to store the dates, and overload the operators.

Another way is to store it as a number (enum) and, when needed, convert it to a string.

You could also write a *function* that accepts two strings, and returns the 'larger' string.

```
std::string funct(std::string first, std::string second){
    if(first == "DEC" || second == "DEC")
        return "DEC";
    if(first == "NOV" || second == "NOV")
        return "NOV";
    ...
}
```